# Find $A \in\mathcal M_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^2 =A$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I have a question: find $A \in\mathcal M_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^2=A$. I came up with these four equations:

$$\begin{cases}a^2+bc=a\\ab+bd=b\\ac+cd=c\\bc+d^2=d\end{cases}$$

Can you guide me how to solve this system of equations?

Comment: what about $a=b=c=d=0$?

Comment: the identity matrix and the null matrix are trivial solutions

Comment: that's the only two by thinking about min poly

Comment: @UnsinkableSam no, there are many other, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)

Comment: @CalvinKhor ah yes you are right

Comment: $b(a+d-1)=0$ means $b=0$ or $d=1-a\dots$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix

Comment: Do you know about similar matrices, linear transformations and vector spaces? These concepts are guaranteed to change your view about this problem drastically!

Comment: If you just want one such $A$, there are a couple of clear examples; compare the corresponding equation for scalars. If you want to parametrize the entire space of such $A$, consider the Jordan normal form of $A$ (and note $A^2 = A$ iff every conjugate of $A$ has the same property).

Comment: In other words, $A$ is an [idempotent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix) matrix

Answer (score 1):

$A:=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is such that $A^2=A$. This is the matrix of the linear projection $p:\mathbb R ^2 \to \mathbb R ^2, (x,y)\mapsto (x,0)$. It is the projection on $\text{Im } p=\mathbb R(1;0)$ parallel to $\text{Ker }p=\mathbb R(0,1)$. Generally speaking, a matrix $A$ such that $A^2=A$ is the matrix of a linear projection $p:\mathbb R ^2 \to \mathbb R ^2(p^2=p)$. This is a classic result of linear algebra. I don't think it's helpful to go through the proposed equations.

Comment: sorry, but we haven't learned about linear projections.

Comment: This is an opportunity to see an example of this. I advise you to make a drawing in the plane for the matrix I have proposed. And maybe that will allow you to come up with another answer for your exercise.

Answer (score 1):

How to solve your system of equations:

$b(a+d-1)=0$ means $b=0$ or $a+d-1=0.$

$c(a+d-1)=0$ means $c=0$ or $a+d-1=0.$

So $d=1-a$, with $bc=a-a^2$, where $a$ is arbitrary,

or $b=0$ and $c=0,$ so $a^2=a$ and $d^2=d$, so $a,d\in\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Following same reasoning in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854227/there-exists-some-real-2-times-2-matrix-a-such-that-a2ai-0/4854602#4854602),
We need
$$
\begin{align}
d &= 1-a, \\
ad &= bc
\end{align}
$$

Choose $a=1, b=1$ and $b\neq 0$, we get $c=0$ and $d=0$.